How to сorrectly recognize 90 and 270 degrees rotated text?
I need to do OCR task on images containing ordinary horizontal text, and, besides this, text with 90 and 270 degree rotation Like this
I use python and PaddleOcr .PaddleOCR can recognize rotated text, but sometimes it doesn't.And, besides this, this programm sometimes doesn't recognize rotated text correctly.I tried to solve the problem by this algoritm:
1.Detect all areas with a text
2.If confidence score of the area is high enough paint it over and save the recognition result
3.Rotate image to 90 degree
4.Repeat steps 1-3 until 360 degree rotation
It doesnt work, because, sometimes the confidence score for a rotated text is higher than the confidence score for horizontal text.Is there a better way to recognize rotated text correctly?

PaddleOCR architecture has three parts as it is shown in the picture below:

text detection detected
boxes rectification
text recognition


To solve your problem you need to focus on 2nd part. PaddleOCR includes a classification model (dir_cls_mv3_slim) that can determine the orientation of the text and rotate it to the correct horizontal alignment.
1. The classification model checks the angle of the detected text region.
2. If the text is rotated (e.g., 90°, 180°, or 270°), it will rotate the text back to 0° (horizontal alignment).

Additionally, fine-tuning can help the model better understand the types of text and orientations it will encounter in your images.

As shown in the picture, there are four more solutions to be considered.



source of image
